# How to access properties from parent class when implementing interface in c#?

Tags: c#, class

If I have an interface

```
interface ISite {
    int g { get; set; }
}
```

and a base class

```
class Site {
    public int g = 1;
}
```

and a derived class that implements the interface and extends the class

```
class DSite : Site, ISite {
    // comaplains g is not defined
}
```

It complains that I did not implement the `g` property, but how do I make it take it from the parent class `Site`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make g in `Site` a property:

```
class Site
{
    public int g {get;set;} = 1;
}
```

or explicitly implement the interface in `DSite`:

```
class DSite : Site, ISite
{
    int ISite.g
    {
        get { return g; }
        set { g = value; }
    }
}
```